# unable to import module serial

Tags: python, pyserial, raspberry-pi4

I'm getting the following for a script on my Raspberry Pi:

```
    import serial
ImportError: No module named serial
```

while the module is already installed with pip:

```
$ pip install pyserial
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.5)
```

How can this be and how can I get the module imported to use?

and I get:

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

Comment: check if install the dependency under the correct python interpreter, pip and python executable should be the same folder

Comment: @ykhrustalev they don't necessarily have to be on the same folder, only the correct virtual environment has to be activated. Tools like poetry and pipenv don't create an environment in the cwd

Comment: @ykhrustalev please see my update in the above post

Comment: @IanAndwati please see my update in the above post

Comment: should be a miracle then, show how you run the scrip please

Comment: @ykhrustalev I run my script with `$ python script.py`

Comment: should be `python3` according to your outputs in the question

Comment: @mistyron try adding the user site packages to your PATH. Alternatively consider using python virtual environments to avoid such pains

Comment: @ykhrustalev using `python3` instead of `python` to invoke my script resolved my problem, you can move this comment into an answer and I'll gladly accept it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your output suggests that you are using this path for installing the packages `/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.5)`

You can check

```
pip freeze
pip3 freeze
/home/pi/.local/bin/pip freeze
/home/pi/.local/bin/pip3 freeze
```

to find which python distribution contains your installed package

Edit: Seems you have resolved it by using the right interpreter which is `python3`